# Why does putting comma selectors inside a space selector break the parent?

Tags: css

I am used to using descendant space selectors and comma selectors. I have ids around larger sets of elements in order to manipulate them easier in jquery and css.

So I tried something like this:

```
#parent_id input, textarea
{
 width: 100px;
}
```

So when I do this, my expectation is that this effect will occur on `input` AND `textarea` inside the `#parent_id`. Instead, this disqualifies `parent_id` and just selects all `input`, `textarea`. Why? And how can I avoid this, aside from making them separate.

Comment: Your current syntax selects all inputs inside id parent_id and ALL textareas in the document.The comma separates different rules and not some sort of concatenation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In CSS, rules have the form:

```
selector0 [, selectorN ]*
{
    property0: value0[,
    property1: value1]*
}
```

So the comma `,` is used to separate different selectors for the same property set. For example, if you wanted two radically different selectors for the same property set.

Selectors in CSS must be fully-qualified, there is no contextual-sensitivity - this is partly because CSS is designed to be forward-compatible: browsers are instructed to try each and every selector in a rule independently, so browsers gracefully-degrade when they encounter new selector syntax they don't support.

To get the effect you want just type more :)

```
#parent_id input,
#parent_id textarea {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Note that there is a proposed/experimental `:matches()` selector function which works as a logical `OR` operator in selectors, it's in the CSS Level 4 Selectors specification (currently in a working-draft state, as of 2016-05-04:  https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/ ).

> The matches-any pseudo-class, :matches(), is a functional pseudo-class taking a selector list as its argument. It represents an element that is represented by its argument.

So in your case it would be:

```
#parent_id :matches( input, textarea ) {
    width: 100px;
}
```

But I don't think this usage is really that better, it's less obvious and requires greater knowledge of CSS.

Comment: From my understanding, each comma selector is an independent statement. Which explains why something like *.class1, class2, class3 { }* won't break, but my question's css will.